# Big palindrome of even length - Wrong Answer

Tags: java, string, performance, replace, palindrome

I have been taking the test on Codility, and trying this exercise:

https://app.codility.com/programmers/trainings/4/disappearing_pairs/

A string S containing only the letters "A", "B" and "C" is given. The string can be transformed by removing one occurrence of "AA", "BB" or "CC".

Transformation of the string is the process of removing letters from it, based on the rules described above. As long as at least one rule can be applied, the process should be repeated. If more than one rule can be used, any one of them could be chosen.

Write a function:

class Solution { public String solution(String S); }

that, given a string S consisting of N characters, returns any string that can result from a sequence of transformations as described above.

For example, given string S = "ACCAABBC" the function may return "AC", because one of the possible sequences of transformations is as follows:

[image]

Also, given string S = "ABCBBCBA" the function may return "", because one possible sequence of transformations is:

[image]

Finally, for string S = "BABABA" the function must return "BABABA", because no rules can be applied to string S.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

the length of string S is within the range [0..50,000];
string S is made only of the following characters: "A", "B" and/or "C".

Here is the code that I tried with a score of 83:

```
public String solution(String S) {
    
    boolean notAA = false;
    boolean notBB = false;
    boolean notCC = false;

    while(S.length()==0 || true){
        if (S.contains("AA")){
            S = S.replace("AA", "");
        } else {
           notAA = true;
        }

        if(S.contains("BB")){
            S = S.replace("BB", "");
        } else {
            notBB = true;
        }

        if(S.contains("CC")){
            S = S.replace("CC", "");
        } else {
            notCC = true;
        }

        if(notAA && notBB && notCC){
            break;
        }
    }
    return S;
}
```

I could not obtain the 100% score because of this:

[image]

even_palindrome1   big palindrome of even length

✘WRONG ANSWER got CACABACABABCBACBACBA.. expected ""

Codility doesn't show me the string example or any other information.

I was reading and reviewing but I still do not understand why I am not getting the right output. My assumption is when I delete the first combination of letters, the string needs to be in a specific state or a specific combination of letters to work correctly and the problem is the palindrome even string.

But, if my assumption is correct, I don't really understand the real cause or root reason for this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, please make sure the question is self-contained; auxiliary links are welcome, but the question should be understandable even if the rest of the internet disappears.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks!!. Just a Question: I dont know if put the entire question is correct or not because belongs to Codility.  I just add it but please confirme me if that ts ok or not to be tranquil with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `notAA`, `notBB` and `notCC` to `false` inside the loop, not before it. The way you are doing it, you find all three, you end the loop.

- Say `S` is `ABCCBA`.
- You set `notAA` and `notBB` to `true`, because `AA` and `BB` cannot be found; then you replace `CC`, giving you `ABBA`.
- Next loop, you set `notAA` to `true` again, remove `BB`, producing `AA`, and set `notCC` to `true`. Now all three are `true` (since `notBB` remained `true` since the first iteration), and you break the loop.
- The result is `AA`, which should have reduced further; but because the program thought there was no `AA`, but it appeared after `notAA` was set, you get the wrong value.

In fact, this can be simplified: you just need a single flag `changed`, which starts before the loop as `true`; then use `while (changed)`. At the top of the loop, set it to `false`, and set it to true every time you successfully replace a substring. You do not need three separate ones, since they all do effectively the same job.

Comment: Thank u really so much for your explanation and for your improvement. I was thinking on that improvemt until i watch your message and its so cool!!!. I will add it right now . This helps me to inprove the way to see everything before coding so thank u so much for that too!!

Answer (score 0):

You should reset `notAA`, `notBB` and `notCC` inside your loop.

Consider, for example, `ABCCBA`.  In your first pass, `notAA` and `notBB` are set to true, leaving `ABBA`.  In the second pass, `notAA` and `notCC` are set to true, leaving `AA`.  Your program would then break out with an available pair because all three conditions are set to true.

Comment: Thank u so much for your help, I didnt think that the issue was so easy, perhaps because i was thinking how to obtain a huge palindrome and never think to use an small one to do the debug. Very good explanation and sorry for do not voting but i need 15 of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, great approach.

The error was, setting the boolean values to `true`.
Instead, you want to set them to whatever the inverted result of `S.contains` is.

A few things I would fix.

First, your while-loop condition includes a `|| true`, which will negate any need for `S.length()==0`.

Additionally, you can reduce the text of your control-flow by using an assignment and a conditional, as follows.

```java
notAA = !S.contains("AA");
if (!notAA) S = S.replace("AA", "");
```

Furthermore, since the final statement within the loop is a conditional-statement that will break the loop, you can, instead, use a do-while loop, and place the conditional there.

```java
public String solution(String S) {
    boolean notAA, notBB, notCC;
    do {
        notAA = !S.contains("AA");
        if (!notAA) S = S.replace("AA", "");
        notBB = !S.contains("BB");
        if (!notBB) S = S.replace("BB", "");
        notCC = !S.contains("CC");
        if (!notCC) S = S.replace("CC", "");
    } while (!notAA || !notBB || !notCC);
    return S;
}
```

If you're familiar with regular expressions, you can reduce your code even further.

```java
String solution(String S) {
    while (S.matches(".*?([ABC])\\1.*"))
        S = S.replaceAll("([ABC])\\1", "");
    return S;
}
```